# how to delete extra line in amsplain-url_bst.bst after URL

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, urls

I use [`amsplain-url.bst`](https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/amsplain-url.bst) for the bibliographic format. When a reference has a URL it adds an extra line before the end of the reference. I want to delete this extra line:

[image: incorrect output]

Comment: where can one find the file `amsplain-url_bst.bst`?  it didn't come directly from ams, and i can't find it on ctan.  (by the way, you really need some extra braces to keep some uppercase letters from getting lost in item 1.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not to mention the lost digits and lowercase letters in item **1**.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Maybe it is [https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/amsplain-url.bst](https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/amsplain-url.bst)?

Comment: this is the file https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/amsplain-url.bst , why i need extra braces? where exactly and this is another view for problem http://postimage.org/image/79ut9p6uv/

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The bst claims >>%%%     filename        = "amsplain.bst"<<, >>%%%     author          = "American Mathematical Society"<< and so on, but is different from the original file.

Comment: @Stephen -- yes, i've found the file.  i will try to figure out why the problem is occurring, but i am *very* unhappy that there is no notice in the changed file that ams is *not* responsible for it any longer because of the changes.  there is no evidence to indicate who made the changes, so it is not going to be easy to get in touch with them to make known our displeasure.  thanks for mentioning this problem.

Comment: is there any similar bst file gets the same result, i want to write paper with reference like these papers http://www.worldscientific.com/toc/ijprai/25/03 i searched for several bst files in lyx until i found amsplain.bst nearly the same as i want but i found the problem of extra line for URLs. So if you know any similar bst file for the previous journal reference working correctly , please help me. thanks so much for your time with me

Comment: even if i used the original file amsplain.bst and i put URLs in notes section , the same error appear (extra line after the http link) so is there any solution or another similar format bst file

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. How does your entry look?